# How to integrate paypal in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, paypal

I need to integrate pay-pal donate in my app, my app is a charity app, so there is no problem in integrating pay-pal within the app. I have found many articles including the pay-pal site for the reference, but nothing seems to be helpful to me, I found a sample code from pay-pal site and I include pay-pal library to my project. In my `applicationDidFinishLaunching` I put

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(initializePayPal) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

-(void)initializePayPal {
    [PayPal initializeWithAppID:@" APP-80W284485P519543T" forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX]; 
}
```

then I don't know what to do with my paypalviewcontroller page in `viewDidLoad`
Anyone have any idea about integrating paypal please help me. I get any simple project source code for reference it would be a great help for me to do. I am really sorry for asking source code. But am a beginner in iPhone.

Comment: You should really put more effort into your question and correct the big amount of typos.

Comment: Are you sure about the first sentence? From the App Store Review Guidelines: `21.2 The collection of donations must be done via a web site in Safari or an SMS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off topic:

I think your app will be rejected

> 11 Purchasing and currencies
>
> 11.1 Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected
>
> 11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be
>   rejected
>
> 11.13 Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, such as a “buy” button that goes
>   to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected

From [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#purchasing-currencies)

On topic:

Look to this [tutorial](https://www.x.com/devzone/articles/iauction-adaptive-tutorial-part-5iphone-sdk-integration).